# "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" ERROR -- NodeJS, MongoDB, React Application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose, jwt

I'm trying to fetch an array from my user database from my react app. The response I'm getting is an HTML file, but I'm not sure why it's not working as I have the same code working perfectly for a non-array element. Here is the code:

Client:

```
  async function populateFavorite() {
    const req = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/favorite", {
      headers: {
        "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem("token"),
      },
    });

    const data = await req.json();
    if (data.status === "ok") {
      console.log(data.watchlist)
    } else {
      alert(data.error);
    }
  }
```

At the moment, it looks like it's not getting past here:

```
const data = await req.json();
```

Server:

```
app.get('/api/favorite', async (req, res) => {
    const token = req.headers['x-access-token']

    try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, '<key>')
        const email = decoded.email
        const user = await User.findOne({ email: email })

        return res.json({ status: 'ok', watchlist: user.watchlist })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.json({ status: 'error', error: 'invalid token' })
    }
})
```

This is what the data looks like in the database:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"627306d86089cb6e720e0e8a"},
"firstName":"Ailany",
"email":"testing@orbit.com",
"coins_owned":[],
"watchlist":["Bitcoin","Serum"],
"dateCreated":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1651705560381"}},
"__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}
```

The goal is to, upon rendering the site, have the client receive the array of items in the user's watchlist to then have them render separately in a list.

*Any help with this would be very appreciated!*

Comment: You're probably getting HTML in response, so did you look at _what_ HTML you're getting?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting a blank HTML page that says "You need Javascript to run this app". When I looked at it, it just looks like a blank React index.html file.

Comment: Then that's probably what it is. You don't show your backend, but I'd guess it's overzealously implementing fallback/SPA/"push state" routing and serving the index file on routes you intended to be API endpoints.

Comment: I'll definitely take a further look, but I don't think that's the problem. I have a "app.post" method that handles the same /api/favorite route which adds/deletes items to the array in the DB. This method has no problems, but I only have an issue when trying to fetch the data.

Comment: It's much easier to confuse a GET than a POST with a visit to a client-side page, if anything that's _supporting_ my theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express uses precedence when defining routes. I had the following code placed above all of my get routes, therefore overriding them.

```
app.get("*", function (request, response) {
  response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../frontend/build", "index.html"));
});
```

Solution:

I moved those lines of code to the bottom so that the other routes would take precedence. Now, I get JSON in the response instead of the index.html.